# Visual Studio Code - NPM not found when using NPM SCRIPTS

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

If I open the integrated terminal and run *npm -v* it works.

[image: Working]

But, if I running it directly from NPM SCRIPTS it doesn't work.

[image: Not working]

**MORE DETAIL AS REQUESTED IN COMMENT**

// Edit by Fogmeister

I also have this problem, here is some more detail...

I have a `test` script defined in `package.json`...

[image]

When I run this script from the root folder command line using `npm run test` it works...

[image]

This script appears in the list of NPM Scripts in VS Code...

[image]

When I run from the NPM Scripts explorer it fails...

[image]

Even though it says it is running from the same folder.

Comment: could you provide task code or it simplified version ??? Does it work from yarn ???

Comment: @SkorpEN I've added a bit more detail that I have for this same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try doing, use dnf or apt-get

```
sudo apt-get/dnf install npm
```

The npm file should be in /usr/local/bin/npm. If it's not there, install node.js again with the package on their website.

Comment:  OK, that was it. I had npm installed in the root directory but not in `/usr/local/bin/` so it wasn't able to find it there. Installed again from the node.js website and it's working perfectly now. Thanks 